# PHP Faker. How to create N unique words?

Tags: php, faker

I need to create N unique words. It seems that 'words' doesn't work with 'unique'.

```
\Faker\Factory::create()->unique()->words(14);
```

...unique()->word() is working. I am trying to create 250 unique words like that:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 250; $i++) {
    $iadefaults[] = $faker->unique()->word();
}
```

but I get

```
Maximum retries of 10000 reached without finding a unique value
```

How can I create those 250 unique words with faker?

Comment: I've found out in empirical way that maximum number of unique words is 182.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution for your issue

Go to Faker's sources and there you'll find a `Provider/Lorem.php` file

At the very top of it there's a   **`protected static $wordList` propery that contains an array defining which words are returned by the generator**. If you do `count(array_count_values($wordList));` - you'll see a magic number of 182 unique words :) No wonder it was unable to get more unique values based on that list.

**So you just need to put more unique words in that array and that will do the trick!**

Comment: But there must be the reason why author limited number of words. Is it about performance? Moreover, if I'll do ```composer update```, then all changes will be lost.

Comment: Perhaps they just didn't pay enough attention to this use-case. I doubt that  adding few hundreds words there would harm performance much. Maybe you should send them more feedback to their repo? (I see you've already left some comments there)